# Is there any way to ban ALL proxy servers from accessing a website using some Apache configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, security, apache2

I am using Apache2 with Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP7.0. I tried using .htaccess setup but that does not seem to work i.e. did not stop anonymous proxies from visiting the website.

I was trying this solution http://www.phpgenious.com/2009/03/block-proxy-servers-using-htaccess/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F]
```

Another option is using  BlockScript https://www.blocked.com/ which seems to be considerably expensive.

Comment: Saying "that does not seem to work" does not really describe the problem very well.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for pointing that out. Basically my process was to include some setting and try to visit the website from an anonymous proxy. The code mentioned in the question does not stop the anonymous proxies.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, writing "please ban all proxy servers" into `.htacces` naturally isn't going to work.... Or did you write something else into it?

Anyway, this isn't possible. A proxy server is no different then a normal web browser and you can't reliably separate proxies from "normal" clients.

Comment: Please see the edit. The solution uses the HTTP header to differentiate proxy servers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which blocks the anonymous proxies. My target audience is limited to a country. So, I used this solution https://coderwall.com/p/dqqz5q/apache-block-specific-countries-using-mod_geoip

and used Geoip to allow only a specific country to my website. It works because the Geoip for anonymous ips appear as A1 etc. (https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/)

So, in case of Ubuntu, in 000-default virtualhost

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    ....
    ....
    # Only allow specific countries
    GeoIPEnable On
    SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GB AllowCountry
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=AllowCountry
</Directory>
```

Here only the country GB i.e. United Kingdom is allowed. I tested this using many anonymous proxy sites (even located in the target country) and the website responds a 403. Access without proxy works fine.

Comment: This technique (using GeoIP or similar blacklisting) is the most-likely to work, but it will depend on updating the proxy list frequently, and you'd likely be wanting some level of (commercial) subscription.

Comment: @CameronKerr yes, you are right. The free GeoIP services are not very accurate.